# 40 Paragraph ended before \align* was complete. <to be read again> this error is showing for alignment severl equations \par

Tags: math-mode, errors, align

My code is like this:

```
\begin{align*}
    V$= - r + 2 M(u,\theta,\phi)+ O(\frac{1}{r})\\
    \beta $=- c(u,\theta,\phi) c* (2 r)^{-2} +O( r^{-4})\\
    h_{AB} dx^{A} dx^{B}$=d(\theta)^{2} + \sin^{2}\theta d(\phi)^{2}\\
    U^{A}$=O( r^{-2})
\end{align*}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) what are those dollar signs doing in something that is already math mode (the align environment)

Comment: Since you used dollars next to equality signs, it seems you're using the wrong character to specify alignment. Try with ampersands, I guess.

Comment: Does your `*` denote a multiplication? If so, you might want to use `\cdot` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wanted to align the "=" signs, in this case, use "&" instead of "$"

```
    \documentclass{article}   
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}    
   \begin{align*}
    V&= - r + 2 M(u,\theta,\phi)+ O(\frac{1}{r})\\
    \beta &=- c(u,\theta,\phi) c* (2 r)^{-2} +O( r^{-4})\\
    h_{AB} dx^{A} dx^{B}&=d(\theta)^{2} + \sin^{2}\theta d(\phi)^{2}\\
    U^{A}&=O( r^{-2})
    \end{align*}
   \end{document}
```

[image]